# Unable to Simulate Click using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, simulate

I have a link for downloading Audio Files. I wish to keep it hidden and allow the user to call it using a button. But somehow I am unable to trigger the click event.

Here is HTML:

```
<a class="APopupDown" data-icon="home" id="DownloadFile" href="http://yahoo.com/abc.mp3" download="My File Name">Download File</a>

<button data-icon="home" href="#" onclick="DlMsg()">Download</button>
```

And here is the trigger.

```
function DlMsg()
{
    alert("I am here");
    $('#DownloadFile').trigger('click');

}
```

A Jfiddle example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EWQ6n/495/)

As you can see the diredct link works but the button doesn't. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

----- UPDATE -------

I have made the change as per Jai's suggestion. However, it now starts playing the Audio instead of downloading, whereas what I want is to use HTML5's download functionality. Here is the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/EWQ6n/514/)

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer. Just see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EWQ6n/512/

Source:

```
<a class="APopupDown" class="test" data-icon="home" id="DownloadFile" href="http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3" download="My File Name">Download File</a>

<button data-icon="home" id="btnDownload">Download</button>
```

Script:

```
$("#btnDownload").click(function(e){
    $("#DownloadFile").get(0).click();
});
```

I just used like this

```
$("#DownloadFile").get(0).click();
```

to trigger the anchor click event.

Comment: Working is JSfiddle but not in the application. I wonder why.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `click` event bound to that element first:

```
$('#DownloadFile').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = this.href;
});
```

then your trigger will work:

```
$('#DownloadFile').trigger('click');
```

#### [Demo @ Fiddle 506](http://jsfiddle.net/EWQ6n/506/)

Comment: It doesn't download the file. It starts playing it within the browser.